# Is Slim actually visible when stuck in the tree?

Tags: a-bugs-life

In Disney Pixar's [*A Bug's Life*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120623/) (1998), near the end, the main characters are chasing the villain Hopper, who is flying away.

Slim (the stick insect) gets stuck among the bushes that Francis (who is carrying him) flies through, at which point the dialogue goes:

> Slim: Francis, Francis, I'm stuck
>
> Francis: Where are you?
>
> Slim: I'm over here
>
> Francis: Where?
>
> Slim: Here, I'm the only stick with eyeballs
>
> [image]

Is Slim actually visible in this scene? We see lots of branches, and the joke is obvious, but I wondered if he is *actually* visible?

I searched online for this, but couldn't find an answer even among the fan-based Wikis. So I assume he's not, but would love to tell my daughter I've found him.

Comment: Haha! I wondered the same thing!

Answer (score 2):

As hard as it is to prove a negative, he doesn't appear to be visible in the scene. If we eliminate every stick where we can see *patterning that doesn't match his exoskeleton*, every branch that we can see *joining to one of the larger branches* and every straight branch *above a certain length that doesn't have any joints*, then there aren't actually an awful lot of places he could be hiding.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow; up vote for effort!

Comment: @EvilDr - I've also twitted at various people involved in the making of the film. Hopefully we'll get a word-of-god on this one, but I wouldn't hold my breath